Enforce HDR to be played as SDR when MacBook is plugged in
I understand the benefits coming from HDR, but some creators use HDR wrong, just to pump up their videos so they look "better". When watching them in dark room with low screen brightness they blind me, because the screen suddenly gets very bright.
example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeOfAN4NqGk
"Optimize video streaming while on battery" is a MacOS setting that plays HDR content as SDR while on battery. It works exactly how I expect, making those HDR videos watchable when the screen brightness is low. However I can't use it when plugged in.
What doesn’t work is Settings -> Displays -> Preset -> "Apple Display (P3-500 nits) as that’s still too bright in a dark room for my needs.
I am hoping there is a kind of system flag, private or documented API or other way to override this setting even when the MacBook is plugged in. But I do not know how to find
How can I always force streamed HDR video to be presented as SDR on macOS even when powered and not just on battery power?

Firefox has an advanced setting in about:config which disables HDR in all macOS energy modes. Search for layout.css.video-dynamic-range.allows-high and toggle it to "false".
